# In which episode does Wesley not know how to open a regular door?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, episode-identification

Picard opens the manual non-sliding glass door for him.

Here's Wil's reference:

Comment: I won't claim to know every TNG episode by heart, but this doesn't ring any bells at all.

Comment: That does ring a bell... the power was out, or something like that during one of their weekly disasters.

Comment: I think it was just a transparent wall without a sliding door.

Comment: Wil says: "Patrick and I did this scene onces, where we were walking into...we're like on a Starbase and Wesly is going to do those Academy tests and I think he's going to have his artificial heart replaced..." There's only one episode I can remember were Wesley took a test, [Coming of Age](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coming_of_Age_%28Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation%29). Though, I can also only remember one episode where Picard got his heart replaced (except for the "Q is God? The universe is not that badly designed!" episode), [Samaritan Snare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samaritan_Snare).

Comment: Man, that guy cutting Wheaton off every few seconds is *really* annoying.

Comment: Ah, while the Pakled plot was entertaining, I mostly blocked out the rest of it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The episode is "[Samaritan Snare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samaritan_Snare)" from the second season.  The door was the hinged all-glass type you might find inside a present-day office building.  Picard and Wesley both approached the door and both stopped as if expecting the other to open it.  Finally Picard opened the door and Wesley held it open for him.  The door had a large metal handle so it seems unlikely that either of them were confused about how to open it.

Comment: Thanks Bobby, thanks Kyle. Add the wikipedia link from above to the answer and I'll accept it. It's at 28:10 into Samaritan Snare. Only very briefly. Hardly worth watching.

Comment: ...I always thought that scene was _really_ weird.  Now I know why.